# Subspace and basis problem

Tags: linear-algebra

I am not sure if the problem is correctly stated.But if it is, I need the proof.
 If A is subspace of B and $A\neq B$, proof that there exists basis of B such that it does not have any of the basis vectors of A.

Comment: Where does this come up? Homework?

Comment: It's a left as an excersice to the reader in my textbook.

Comment: What field are these vector spaces over?

Comment: Over real numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may mean that, given a basis of $A$, there exists a basis for $B$ with none of the vectors of the given $A$-basis as elements. That was my original interpretation, and to prove that, try doubling all the basis vectors in your basis of $A$, then extending to a basis for $B$.

It may instead mean one of the following:

> (i) There is a basis for $B$ without any vectors from *any* $A$-basis.
>
> (ii) There is a basis for $B$ without any $A$-basis as a subset.

In either of these cases, we will need for $A$ to be a **proper** subspace of $B$. A basis that works for (i) will also work for (ii), and will also work for my original interpretation in the case that $A$ is a proper subspace of $B$. Start with a basis $C$ for $A,$ and take any vector $x\in B$ that isn't in $A$. Let $D=\{x\}\cup\{v+x:v\in C\}$. Show that this is linearly independent, contains no vectors of $A$, and that $A$ is contained in the span of $D$. Then extend $D$ to a basis of $B$ if necessary. This basis will will then have no vectors of $A$ in it, at all.

I leave it to you to verify the details (that is, make it an actual proof, rather than just a proof idea).

Comment: I don't understand this answer. Doubling the vectors in the basis gives you another basis for $A$.

Comment: The phrase "***the*** basis vectors for $A$" suggests that we are fixing a basis of $A$, then showing that there exists a basis for $B$ containing none of those vectors.

Comment: Ah. I took it to mean, there exists a basis of $B$ containing no basis of $A$ as one of its subsets.

Comment: Hmmm.... Now that I think about it, it may mean yet a third thing.

Comment: You're right, it could mean, there exists a basis of $B$ that contains no elements of $A$.

Comment: If D is not a basis of B, then there exists an element $x_1 \in B$ for which $x_1$ is not in the span of D. Then I can take it as a basis vector in $D_1=\{x_1\} \cup {D}$. If I repeat this I will finally obtain basis of B. Is that what you mean by extending the basis?

Comment: @user61810: Yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: But if the system D is not linearly independent then there exist constants $c_1, c_2,...,c_{n+1}$ such that: $(c_1+c_2+...+c_{n+1})x =- c_2 v_1 -c_3v_2-...-c_{n+1}v_n$ What if the sum $c_1+c_2+...c_{n+1}=0$? I cannot prove the linear independence in this case.

Comment: Oh, wait, if the sum is 0, then it will mean that $c_2v_1+c_3v_2+...+c_{n+1}v_n=0$ and because $v_1, v_2,...v_n$ are linearly independent, then $c_2=c_3=...=c+{n+1}=0$ and therefore $c_1 =0$. Which is a contradiction. Am I right?

Comment: @user61810: Exactly! Excellent work.

Answer (score 0):

The claim is wrong for general vector spaces. Look at the $\mathbb{F}_2$ vector space $B = \mathbb{F}_2$ and also take it as the subspace $A$. There is only a single basis of $A$ and $B$, namely $\{1\}$.

Comment: Obviously $A\neq B$

Comment: @user61810: No. $B$ is a subspace of $B$, so $A = B$ is allowed.

Comment: In this problem A=B is not allowed.

Comment: @user61810: So why don't you tell us when stating the exercise in the question?

Comment: I said clearly I am not sure if it was correct. The case which you pointed out shouldn't be considered. Thank you.

Comment: @user61810: The question comes from your textbook. So why not just giving us the original statement?

Comment: @user61810: You don't need to worry about azimut's counterexample, since your field is the reals. We can allow $A=B$ with no problem.

Comment: Why all these downvotes?